# Customizing form displayed by x-editable

Tags: x-editable

I want to dynamically change the appearance of the form displayed by x-editable, e.g., adding extra text both to the body and titlebar of the popup.  How do I do this? (I didn't see a callback in the documentation that seemed to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is now callback function, the only way to do this AFAIK, is to use `setTimeout()` (generally not a good practice in JS programming).

```
jQuery('.editable_class').click(function() {
   var that = this;
   setTimeout(function() {
       jQuery('.editableform', jQuery(that).closest('.container')) // manipulate stuff on this object
   }, 100);    
}).editable(options);
```